# Erlang: Make a ring

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I'm quite new to Erlang (Reading through "Software for a Concurrent World"). From what I've read, we link two processes together to form a reliable system.

But if we need more than two process, I *think* we should connect them in a ring. Although this is slightly tangential to my actual question, please let me know if this is incorrect.

Given a list of `PIDs`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to form these in a ring of `{My_Pid, Linked_Pid}` tuples:

```
[{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,1}]
```

I have trouble creating an elegant solution that adds the final `{5,1}` tuple.

Here is my attempt:

```
% linkedPairs takes [1,2,3] and returns [{1,2},{2,3}]
linkedPairs([])         -> [];
linkedPairs([_])        -> [];
linkedPairs([X1,X2|Xs]) -> [{X1, X2} | linkedPairs([X2|Xs])].

% joinLinks takes [{1,2},{2,3}] and returns [{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}]
joinLinks([{A, _}|_]=P) ->
    {X, Y} = lists:last(P)
    P ++ [{Y, A}].

% makeRing takes [1,2,3] and returns [{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}]
makeRing(PIDs) -> joinLinks(linkedPairs(PIDs)).
```

I cringe when looking at my `joinLinks` function - `list:last` is slow (I think), and it doesn't look very "functional".

Is there a better, more idiomatic solution to this?

If other functional programmers (non-Erlang) stumble upon this, please post your solution - the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if we need more than two process, I think we should connect them
>   in a ring.

No.  For instance, suppose you want to download the text of 10 different web pages.  Instead of sending a request, then waiting for the server to respond, then sending the next request, etc., you can spawn a separate process for each request.  Each spawned process only needs the pid of the main process, and the main process collects the results as they come in.  When a spawned process gets a reply from a server, the spawned process sends a message to the main process with the results, then terminates. The spawned processes have no reason to send messages to each other.  No ring.

I would guess that it is unlikely that you will ever create a ring of processes in your erlang career.

> I have trouble creating an elegant solution that adds the final {5,1} tuple.

You can create the four other processes passing them `self()`, which will be different for each spawned process.  Then, you can create a separate branch of your `create_ring()` function that terminates the recursion and returns the pid of the last created process to the main process:

```
init(N) ->
    LastPid = create_ring(....),

create_ring(0, PrevPid) -> PrevPid;
create_ring(N, PrevPid) when N > 0 ->
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [PrevPid]),
    create_ring(.......).
```

Then, the main process can call (not spawn) the same function that is being spawned by the other processes, passing the function the last pid that was returned by the `create_ring()` function:

```
init(N) ->
    LastPid = create_ring(...),
    loop(LastPid).
```

As a result, the main process will enter  into the same message loop as the other processes, and the main process will have the last pid stored in the loop parameter variable to send messages to.

In erlang, you will often find that while you are defining a function, you won't be able to do everything that you want in that function, so you need to call another function to do whatever it is  that is giving you trouble, and if in the second function you find you can't do everything you need to do, then you need to call another function, etc.  Applied to the ring problem above, I found that `init()` couldn't do everything I wanted in one function, so I defined the `create_ring()` function to handle part of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use `lists:zip` with the original list and its 'rotated' version:

```
1> L=[1,2,3].
[1,2,3]
2> lists:zip(L, tl(L) ++ [hd(L)]).
[{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}]
```

Comment: Ah, that's a great way to rotate it – I was searching for a `rotate` function. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you are manipulating long lists, you can avoid the creation of the intermediary list `tl(L) ++ [hd(L)]` using an helper function:

```
1> L = lists:seq(1,5).
[1,2,3,4,5]
2> Link = fun Link([Last],First,Acc) -> lists:reverse([{Last,First}|Acc]);                 
              Link([X|T],First,Acc) -> Link(T,First,[{X,hd(T)}|Acc]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.42.127694169>
3> Joinlinks = fun(List) -> Link(List,hd(List),[]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.127694169>
4> Joinlinks(L).
[{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,1}]
5>
```